# Add / Upload text files in phpMyAdmin db, or WordPress site

Tags: php, wordpress, phpmyadmin

I am not sure if i will need a WordPress plugin or a PHP script.

I am trying to upload 1 million articles in text files in WordPress post with localhost/wordpress and xampp.

Until now I found 3 ways:

1. gsa ser but it can work with 1 thread per site
2. with xrumer but it post duplicate articles
3. with seo content machine but it work with 1 thread.

As you can see with 1 thread I need a month to upload 1 millions text to wordpress posts.

Questions:

1. Can I use any script or something to upload lets say more than 100 text files per second or so
2. Can I use any script to upload text files directly in phpMyAdmin db
3. Does anyone have faced a similiar situation in past, and how you manage it

Comment: You can use a script to do this, but writing one is really a bit beyond the scope of what this site is for. phpMyAdmin *probably* won't help you, since you have a million articles to import and phpMyAdmin really functions on individual files — however, you might have luck concatenating the files together before import. I wouldn't, though; I'd use Python or PHP or some other scripting language to iterate over each file and load the contents in to the database.

Answer (score 0):

Use GSA SER
make the threads to 100 from:

> options -> submission tab -> modify the threads to use

I didn't test it if it will post in 1 thread or not
but you can:

1. duplicate the project as many times you need, so it is guarantee to use at least 1 thread per 1 project.

> right click on the project -> Modify project -> duplicate -> just data
>   and options

2. you can also create multiple accounts in your wordpress and insert it to the SER project.

> right click on the project -> Modify project -> import -> account data